# WARNING: Base.writemime is deprecated. Julia 0.5 with Jupyter

Tags: julia, jupyter-notebook

When I use Julia 0.5 with Jupyter, I have sometimes the warning.

```
WARNING: Base.writemime is deprecated.
```

When I use Julia 0.5 with REPL, I don't have this warning.

What shoud I do?

When I build Ijulia, I had the warning and I wonder if these are related.

```
Pkg.build("IJulia”)

WARNING: `@windows_only` is deprecated, use `@static if is_windows()` instead
 in depwarn(::String, ::Symbol) at ./deprecated.jl:64
 in @windows_only(::Any) at ./deprecated.jl:489
 in include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:426
 in evalfile(::String, ::Array{String,1}) at ./loading.jl:442 (repeats 2 times)
 in cd(::##2#4, ::String) at ./file.jl:59
 in (::##1#3)(::IOStream) at ./none:13
 in open(::##1#3, ::String, ::String) at ./iostream.jl:113
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:234
 in process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:239
 in _start() at ./client.jl:318
while loading /Users/hogehoge/.julia/v0.5/Nettle/deps/build.jl, in expression starting on line 8
WARNING: Base.OS_NAME is deprecated.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a deprecation warning. It still works. It's just notifying the developers that on v0.5 that function is being deprecated and should be replaced. Many packages on v0.5 will right now have deprecation warnings to help package developers update their packages.

Note that you are using v0.5. v0.5-rc0, the release candidate for v0.5, is a beta release. It's for package developers to have a version of Julia to target for compatibility. If you're not very familiar with Julia, it's recommended you use the current release, which as of right now is v0.4.6 (which won't have any of these warnings).

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.
I will try v0.4.6.

Comment: I downloaded v0.4.6 and the warnings are cleared!
Thank you so much.

Comment: @SEG61319 If the solution from Chris worked for you, you can then also click on the green "check" arrow next to the answer to let future people who view this question easily see that the issue was resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I clicked the green check.